# Open an Adobe XD web link using Adobe XD app

Tags: macos, ios, adobe-xd

I have received an Adobe XD web document link from a client. It contains the design and flow for an iPhone app designed keeping iPhone 7 screen size (4.7") and resolution (1334 x 750) in mind. It's a public link and is **not** shared with me via Adobe cloud.

I am able to view the link alright in a Web browser. However, I wish to view the design on an actual iPhone to better understand the on-screen elements size and placement. However, I am unable to do so.

I have both the Adobe XD macOS and iOS app installed (I have an active Adobe CC subscription if that matters). However, I am unable to find a way to access the prototype using either the desktop or mobile app.

Am I missing something? Or is it not possible to view a link shared directly within the Adobe XD app?